# Apache - MySQL XAMPP errors occurred Service detected in the wrong path

Tags: mysql, xampp

When I try to start the MySQL on XAMPP this error messages shows.
I tried changing the port and also tried to uninstall the XAMPP but cant completely uninstall it.
I wasn't able to find a proper solution on google, so I'm kinda' hoping someone could help me out with this.
Oh and, XAMPP is running properly. Apache and the MySQL service are both running ..

```
`11:04:38 PM  [main]    Initializing Modules
11:04:38 PM  [mysql]    MySQL Service detected with wrong path
11:04:38 PM  [mysql]    Change XAMPP MySQL and Control Panel settings or
11:04:38 PM  [mysql]    Uninstall/disable the other service manually first
11:04:38 PM  [mysql]    Found Path: "C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\bin\mysqld.exe" 
            "--defaults-file=C:\Program Files\MariaDB 10.3\data\my.ini" 
            "MySQL"
11:04:38 PM  [mysql]    Expected Path: c:\new folder\xampp\mysql\bin\mysqld.exe 
            --defaults-file=c:\new folder\xampp\mysql\bin\my.ini mysql
11:04:38 PM  [main]     Starting Check-Timer
11:04:38 PM  [main]     Control Panel Ready
11:04:40 PM  [mysql]    Attempting to start MySQL service...`
```

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the same problem. The solution that worked for me is :

1. Run the XAMPP in the administrator mode. Go to the XAMPP control panel.
2. In the modules section, in the 'Service' column, we are provided with checkboxes.'
3. For the services that you are facing problems with, click on the corresponding checkbox to uninstall the service.
4. Also, click on the same checkbox again to re-install the service.